# Does pysvn work with Python 3.2 on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysvn

I've got the pysvn module working great in Python 2.7.1, but it refuses to import in Python 3.2. It was installed with apt-get, so I figured it should work for both.

```
xxxxx:~$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:12:17)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysvn
>>> exit()

xxxxx:~$ python3
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Oct 20 2012, 14:09:29)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysvn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pysvn
>>> exit()
```

edit:
I've tried installing the 3.2 version through pip as well, here's the results

```
xxxxx:~$ sudo pip-3.2 install http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.8.tar.gz  Downloading/unpacking http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.8.tar.gz
  Downloading pysvn-1.7.8.tar.gz (347kB): 347kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.8.tar.gz

Cleaning up...
xxxxx:~$ python3
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Oct 20 2012, 14:09:29)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysvn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pysvn
```

Comment: You'd need to install it separately for python3 (python 2 and 3 look in different places for packages). It looks like ubuntu doesn't have a python3 version. I'm not sure if it's the same codebase -- if it is you could try just adjusting `sys.path` to find it. It would be better to install it for python3 though, either using `pip` or manually.

Answer (score 3):

[python3-svn](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/python3-svn) has been included into Ubuntu distribution only since 16.10 Yakkety. For those having older Ubuntu versions the information below may help.

This is how I built and installed pysvn for Python3 on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit (and later on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit):

1. Already had subversion and python3.
2. Installed **libsvn-dev**: `sudo apt-get install libsvn-dev`. This will also install libapr1-dev.
3. Downloaded pysvn-1.9.3.tar.gz from the Tigris website and unpacked it into a temp directory. The latest tar-balls from Tigris already include pycxx sources.
4. Changed the lines `'../Import/pycxx-%d.%d.%d' % pycxx_version,` to `'../Import/pycxx-6.2.8',` in the unpacked **setup_configure.py** file, so that it pointed to the unpacked pycxx directory. The `--pycxx-dir` parameter not worked for me, hence the brute hardcoding. It may work for your case, though, so you may want to try it first (see the comment from @djangonaut).
5. Run

   `python3 setup.py configure \ 
    --svn-lib-dir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ \
    --apr-lib-dir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ \
    --verbose`

   The two additional dir parameters point to the directory where libsvn_client-1.so and libapr-1.so are. On 64-bit system it's gonna be `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.
6. Run `make` to actually build the library.
7. Run unit tests: `cd ../Tests`, `make`.
8. Installed the built library:

   `cd ../Source
   sudo mkdir /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysvn
   sudo cp pysvn/__init__.py /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysvn/
   sudo cp pysvn/*.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pysvn/`
9. Done.

This is mostly what is described in the INSTALL.html file from the pysvn sources, with some tweaks.

Comment: nice instruction, but doesn't work:
:~/Downloads/pysvn-1.9.6/Source$ python3 setup.py configure
Info: Configure for python 3.6.5 in exec_prefix /home/hubert/.pyenv/versions/untitled-project
Error: Cannot find PyCXX include CXX/Version.hxx - use --pycxx-dir

Comment: With 1.9.10 the pycxx-dir parameter worked: `python setup.py configure --pycxx-dir=../Import/pycxx-7.1.3/`

Answer (score 1):

Cannot add comment to leave a link, so put it here:

My way on linux:

Get sources from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pysvn/files/pysvn/V1.9.10/pysvn-1.9.10.tar.gz/download)

```
tar -zxf pysvn-1.9.10.tar.gz
apt-get install subversion libsvn1 libsvn-dev make g++
cd pysvn-1.9.10/Source
python setup.py configure --pycxx-dir=/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/
make
```

Here i've got errors below:

```
Compile: /pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxsupport.cxx into cxxsupport.o
/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxsupport.cxx:42:10: fatal error: Src/Python3/cxxsupport.cxx: No such file or directory
#include "Src/Python3/cxxsupport.cxx"

Compile: /pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxextensions.c into cxxextensions.o
/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxextensions.c:42:10: fatal error: Src/Python3/cxxextensions.c: No such file or directory
#include "Src/Python3/cxxextensions.c"
```

It is needed to edit that files:
`vi /pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxsupport.cxx`

```
change #include "Src/Python3/cxxsupport.cxx" to
#include "Python3/cxxsupport.cxx"
```

and same on second file. Than `make` again:

```
make clean && make
...
Compile: /code/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxxextensions.c into cxxextensions.o
Compile: /code/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/IndirectPythonInterface.cxx into IndirectPythonInterface.o
Compile: /code/pysvn-1.9.10/Import/pycxx-7.1.3/Src/cxx_exceptions.cxx into cxx_exceptions.o
Link pysvn/_pysvn_3_7.so
```

Then just copy it to the site-packages (change to yours directory):

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysvn
cp /code/pysvn-1.9.10/Sources/pysvn/__init__.py /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
cp /code/pysvn-1.9.10/Sources/pysvn/_pysvn*.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu distributes the packages for Python 2 and Python 3 separately as different source code has to be used for the two major versions of Python. Typically the Python 3 package is prefixed with `python3` instead of `python`. No Python 3 pysvn package seems to exist in Ubuntu though pysvn supports Python 3.